# Embed conditional range of cells into body of outlook email VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am currently using Ron De Bruin's email range/selection VBA, however I need to find a way to change it in order to fit the data I have. I currently have a large data table which contains stock trading information, with column A of the table specifying the date of the trades. I've attached a screenshot of a dummy example below for reference.

[image]

The macro would be used once a day, and what I am looking for it to do is to embed the cells with only today's date into the body of the outlook email. So, the end of the day email would include all the day's trading activity from today etc.I have attached RDB's macro below for reference. Any help guidance on this would be awesome, thank you!

```
Sub Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").UsedRange

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = 
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"


    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This will include your headers (Date, Account,  Side etc..) + today's date in the mail body by filtering these values in your workbook before sending.

I assume you only have to Column L (12) in your dataset i.e. `Cells(lrow, 12)` and `Cells(Rows.Count, 12)` is set to 12.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim MyDate As Date

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection

    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MyDate = Date

    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData 'Unfilter all data
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lrow, 12)).AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:= _
        Array("Date"), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
        Criteria2:=Array(2, MyDate) 'Add criteria to filter

    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 12)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'Copy only filtered data
    'Set rng = ActiveSheet.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "" 'Your email
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send   'or use .Display (.Send - Send email directly, .Display don't send email)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".html"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: thanks @Wizhi, though I'm slightly confused. Will this let me send out the columns/rows which match today's date?

Comment: Yes, this lines creates today's date `MyDate = Date` and we filter on `MyDate`: `Criteria2:=Array(2, MyDate)`

Comment: Ah okay, i've tried the vba a few times but it crashes Excel for me, I end up needing to reboot the program.

Comment: I tested it now and seems to work.. I will send you my example sheet where I tested the code in better details in the evening :)!!. Will be home in about 3 hours

Comment: Thanks Wizhi, really appreciate all of this help!

Comment: Np, I already made the workbook earlier. See if this [copy](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k9z54g5upbrwyfb/Book2.xlsm?dl=0) works better :)

Comment: Hi Wizhi, I've tried to use your VBA in my file but unfortunately it continues to cause Excel to crash. Could it be due to the number of cells the VBA has to filter on my main data sheet in order to find the correct date? (Its over 1200 rows of data)

Comment: EDIT: After loading it produces this message: Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action. Could this mean the issue is related to outlook?

Comment: Quite puzzled why it doesn't work, I want to agree. Think maybe it's Outlook that's preventing the script... maybe any of these [can help you?](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/excel-is-waiting-for-another-application). // Just ideas...1. In my Library reference I have "OLE Automation" checked". 2. I know on my home computer you need to click manually on the security warning that's [pop up from Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsTsW.png). Maybe something that can help you :)

Comment: Thanks Wizhi, I've tried a couple of those options from the article but unfortunately they did not work, some of them stopped me from being able to open the excel file all together. Thank you so much for all the help on this and my previous questions, perhaps its just not a compatible vba request with my dataset.

Comment: Sad and strange, do have the possibility to test your file/the copy I gave on another computer?. Could maybe be a specific computer...

Comment: I will attempt to test it tonight on my laptop at home. Will keep you updated with what happens. Thank you so much again!